# How is it possible to have ClassCastException after instanceof returns true

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following code snippet from [Android's Pair.java](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=-0F0FCOc_Dgka3ovb86Swu0zffI&cid=OpnM-8VCwHE&s=Pair.java%20Android&browser=Default#L44)

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
    final Pair<F, S> other;
    try {
        other = (Pair<F, S>) o;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return first.equals(other.first) && second.equals(other.second);
}
```

I was wondering, how is it possible to have ClassCastException, after `instanceof` returns true.

Comment: check your import. Maybe you are importing two different Pair class

Comment: Looks impossible. Post full code sample.

Comment: You aren't getting a `ClassCastException`, are you? It should be impossible in this case. Just because you found code somewhere that catches some random exception doesn't mean this exception can actually be thrown.

Comment: It's possible your F and/or S class is the one throwing the ClassCastException.  Post full code sample or a stack trace, please.

Comment: Full code is already posted as external link in the question. That's the official code from Android

Comment: What are `F` and `S`?  I suspect their `equals` implementations of being the ones throwing the CCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible. The code makes no sense. Whoever wrote it probably didn't understand that `F` and `S` are erased at runtime so a `ClassCastException` could never happen.

Comment: The code are from Google Android engineers. Possible they see something we don't notice?

Comment: Same guess from me. Anyone can go wrong, including Googlers :)